# Trouble changing primitive attributes

Tags: modeling

When creating a primitive in blender, the attribute section is greyed out and I can't change anything. I'm using blender 2.8. Is this feature just not in yet or ?

Comment: HI, which "attribute section" are you talking about? Try to add a screenshot of the values you can't change (edit your question and upload it through the image tool)

Comment: Hey sorry,It was when creating like a cylinder and not being able to change number of sections and what not. I found the answer , which was to change global undo in preferences

Answer (score 1):

Adding a response, because I came here looking for an answer.

Blender 2.80 (beta), as of 2019-feb-02 nightly build:

The parameters for a newly added primitive are not in the T-side-panel (as previously in Blender 2.79).

Instead they have a pop-up panel in lower-left corner overlaying the 3D-View.

When you first start running Blender-2.80, this pop-up may be minimized (as shown in the first image). Click this to open this panel. It may remain automatically opened for newly added primitives after you open it the first time.

[image: image showing panel closed]

[image: image showing panel opened]